Remove p-timeline-event-opposite space from PrimeNG Timeline in Angular 17
I am using the PrimeNG Timeline module to display a couple of simple horizontal timelines with content on the top side in a table. How can I remove the space taken up from the .p-timeline-event-opposite section? When I use the chrome debugger and select the timeline element the .pitimeline-event-opposite is always there taking up space.
I am following the Horizontal example here: https://primeng.org/timeline#horizontal
But even there you can see a lot of space between the timelines because the opposite section is taking up room.
Here is my code:
<tr>
  <td>Test label in front</td>
  <td>
    <p-timeline [value]="events" layout="horizontal" align="center">
      <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-event title="event" style="display: none;">
      </ng-template>
    </p-timeline>
  </td>
  <td>Test label after</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td >Test label in front</td>
  <td >
    <p-timeline [value]="events" layout="horizontal" align="center">
      <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-event title="event">
      </ng-template>
    </p-timeline>
  </td>
  <td>Test label after</td>
</tr>

Events is just an array of strings:
events: string[] = [
    "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 2", "Test 4", "Test 5", "Test 6", "Test 7""
  ];


It is due to the internal styling of prime-ng, so you need to override it manually using the below CSS.
.custom-end-width .p-timeline-horizontal .p-timeline-event:last-child {
  min-width: 33px !important;
}

Note: I am using a class to control where the style gets applied, we need to add the CSS to global-styles.css to apply it. Also add the same class on the HTML.
<div class="card flex flex-column gap-3 custom-end-width">
  <p-timeline [value]="events" layout="horizontal" align="top">
    <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-event> {{ event }} </ng-template>
  </p-timeline>
  <p-timeline [value]="events" layout="horizontal" align="bottom">
    <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-event> {{ event }} </ng-template>
  </p-timeline>
  <p-timeline [value]="events" layout="horizontal" align="alternate">
    <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-event> {{ event }} </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="opposite" let-event>
      <span>&nbsp;</span>
    </ng-template>
  </p-timeline>
</div>

Stackblitz Demo

I looked at your stackblitz demo and do not think that is working. You still have the space in between each timeline and when I use debugger tools you can see the opposite section still there. I am trying to get the multiple timelines closer together vertically.

@Ben as per your question I removed what you said, either use the same approach and get rid of the other unnecessary space, or share a screenshot of exact output you need, for me to check the same.

I am not able to upload images or screenshots to comments here. I just ran your stackblitz demo again and its the same thing. You can see in between the second and bottom timelines, there is a lot of extra space. If you open debugger tools you will see there is a 14px padding added to that .p-timeline.p-timeline-horizontal .p-timeline-event-opposite section.

Im facing the same problem but with the vertical mode... After research about it i solved it overriding the .p-timeline-event-opposite class with display none. I don't know what version are you using but maybe it will works to you too. Put this code in your component css/sass file.
::ng-deep .p-timeline-event-opposite {
    display: none;
}

I know it's not the most elegant solution, but at least it works. :P

Add this in styles.scss


.p-timeline-event-opposite {
  display: none !important;
}



